# Nlog: how to write logger without namespace?

Tags: c#, nlog

I try to modify my nlog confile file - how it looks like this:

```
layout="${longdate}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|version:${appVersion}|${message:withexception=true}"
```

And in logs looks like:

```
2023-01-12 13:34:20.7639|0|INFO|Some.My.Namespace.App.MyService|version:1.0.30.0|some text
```

How to make string like:

```
2023-01-12 13:34:20.7639|0|INFO|MyService|version:1.0.30.0|some text
```

Is it possible to do?

Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: Official documentation [here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logger-Layout-Renderer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this:

```
layout="${longdate}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger:shortName=true}|version:${appVersion}|${message:withexception=true}"/>
```

Main thing:

```
${logger:shortName=true}

2023-01-12 13:34:20.7639|0|INFO|MyService|version:1.0.30.0|some text
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logger-Layout-Renderer